# Parsing specific data using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I have a webpage which has tabular data in it. The following is the HTML code for the table:

```
    <table class="confluenceTable">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <th class="confluenceTh">
             <p>Prefix</p>
          </th>
          <th class="confluenceTh">
             <p>Group</p>
          </th>
          <th class="confluenceTh">
             <p>Contact</p>
          </th>
          <th class="confluenceTh">
             <p>Dev/Test Lab</p>
          </th>
          <th class="confluenceTh">
             <p>Performance</p>
          </th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p> </p>
          </td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p> </p>
          </td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p> </p>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th class="confluenceTh">
             <p> </p>
          </th>
          <th class="confluenceTh">
             <p> </p>
          </th>
          <th class="confluenceTh">
             <p> </p>
          </th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p>SEF00</p>
          </td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p>APTRA Vision</p>
          </td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p> </p>
          </td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p><a href="/somepage">VCD Lab</a> , <a href="/somepage">Test Lab</a></p>
          </td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p><a href="/display">Perf Lab</a></p>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p>SEF01</p>
          </td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p>In-Person Bill Payment</p>
          </td>
          <td class="confluenceTd">
             <p>Swamy PKV</p>
          </td>
```

How can I format my Python code so that I just get all data underneath Prefix and Group columns. So far I have tried this:

```
ii=1
data=requests.get(url,auth=(username,password))
sample=data.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(sample,'html.parser')
for row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:154]:
     datatocheck.append(row.get_text(separator='\t'))
while(ii<=152):
        print datatocheck[ii][0:30]
        ii+=1
```

This gives me the following output:

```
SEF00   APTRA Vision        VCD Lab  
SEF01   In-Person Bill Payment  S
```

But I just want `SEF00`(prefix) and `APTRA Vision`(group), `SEF01` and `In-Person Bill Payment`. Not the other columns.

Also, I cant change my HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

How about if u do 
    If SEF00 in ii:

It may print just the SEF00

Comment: I did not quite get that. Can you add a sample code block please?

Comment: I m not home I'm posting by my iPhone so, I gonna se if it works if it does I'll post here what I thought u should do is ask Python to print the string if it has SEF00 on it u know

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for row in soup.find_all('tr')[3:]:   # remove empty row
    tds = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in row.find_all('td')]
    print(tds[0],tds[1])
```

out:

```
SEF00 APTRA Vision
SEF01 In-Person Bill Payment
```

just get all the td in the row, put them in a list, than slice it

Comment: Ok will do but is it an issue if I am using HTML.parser instead of lxml? I tried pip installing lxml but it always fails..

Comment: at print(tds[0],tds[1]), I keep getting IndexError: list index out of range ERROR message. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anyway, the other solution you gave yesterday worked. Thanks once again!